# Adding client cache via httpmodule for custom folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

I am currently using  within web.config of my project.

```
<location path="js">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="8765:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="css">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="8765:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This would be fine if I only wanted to cache a few folders here and there but I have javascript and css in a number of other places that I also want to cache and have opted to use HttpModule to cache these directories there.

Ive been doing a bit of research and came across [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) on clientCache which shows me how to update it in the httpModule using c#

```
  using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
  { 
     Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");
     ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");

     ConfigurationElement clientCacheElement = staticContentSection.GetChildElement("clientCache");
     clientCacheElement["cacheControlMode"] = @"UseMaxAge";
     clientCacheElement["cacheControlMaxAge"] = @"8765:00:00";

     serverManager.CommitChanges();
  }
```

My question is, is it possible to specify the exact folders I want to cache using this method? For example if I have a folder with javascript in the following directory: siteMap/js how do I tell my httpModule to set the clientCache for that explicit folder?

Comment: When you call `Configuration.GetSection` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.configuration.getsection?view=iis-dotnet#Microsoft_Web_Administration_Configuration_GetSection_System_String_System_String_ you should provide a valid location path that matches the XML element. Then what you wanted can be easily achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example. if you want to set clientcache for folder "Scripts" by adding section `<location="Scripts">` in web.config.

Then you could try this config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent", "**Scripts**"); .

```
  using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");

            ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent", "Scripts");

            ConfigurationElement clientCacheElement = staticContentSection.GetChildElement("clientCache");
            clientCacheElement["cacheControlMode"] = @"UseMaxAge";
            clientCacheElement["cacheControlMaxAge"] = TimeSpan.Parse("8765.00:00:00");

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```